# python circular import and definition of exception classes

Tags: python

I know the way that python acts with circular imports through creating references in `sys.modules`. But please see these two modules and the problem with defining an exception class:

**a.py**

```
import b
class Err(Exception):
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        b.f()
    except Err:
        pass
```

**b.py**

```
from a import Err
def f():
    raise Err()
```

**Seems that we should catch the Err but it's not correct.** The output of running a.py is:

```
$ python a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 8, in <module>
    b.f()
  File "b.py", line 4, in f
    raise Err()
a.Err
```

Ok, now let we add some logs to the code to make it more clear:

**a.py:**

```
print 'A1'
import b
print 'A2'

class Err(Exception):
    pass

print 'A3', 'id(Err)=%x' % id(Err)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        b.f()
    except Err:
        pass
```

**b.py**

```
print 'B1'
from a import Err

print 'B2', 'id(Err)=%x' % id(Err)

def f():
    raise Err()
```

The output is:

```
$ py a.py
A1
B1
A1
A2
A3 id(Err)=23fa750
B2 id(Err)=23fa750
A2
A3 id(Err)=23f9740
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 12, in <module>
    b.f()
  File "b.py", line 7, in f
    raise Err()
a.Err
```

As you can see python defines `Err` two times and there is two different class object for `Err` at `0x23fa750` and `0x23f9740`. If you test an instance of `b.Err` with `isinstance` function and `a.Err` class you will get `False`. So the only way to catch the exception is to use `b.Err` instead of `Err`. But it's not what we expect at first sight and it's not what we want.

**The solution** that I know is to create a new module `c.py` and define `Err` class in it. Then both `a.py` and `b.py` should import `Err` from `c.py`. It solves this problem.

**But** is there a solution that allow us to define `Err` in `a.py`? Note that the problem is not just about exception classes, any python class may fall into this pit based on how we use its objects in our code.

Comment: No, It doesn't solve the problem. It's believable that a.Err should point to the new class object but if you print its id in "f" function before raise you will see it is the old one. @Evert

Comment: I find out trying myself. I think the problem here may be the case that module `a` also functions as the `main` module, and that causes the different ids. If you'd log the classes for `Err`, it will be something like `<class 'a.Err'>` and `<class '__main__.Err'>`. I'd be curious but doubtful whether that can be avoided here.

Comment: That's right, if we add c.py with 'import b, a' and test try/catch there, we will not see the unhandled exception with each of a.Err and b.Err. It's because we change the order of import from 'a, b' to 'b, a'. In this case just one class object of Err will be create. In c.py you must import b at the first, import a at the first will make import error.

Answer (score 1):

When you add an `if __name__ == '__main__':` at the end of a module then reference things defined in the preceding code, it's *not* that same as importing and using the module (the `__main__` module is not cached in `sys.modules`, for one thing). You can get your first example to work correctly with the following modification:

**a.py**

```
import b
class Err(Exception):
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from a import Err  # add this
    try:
        b.f()
    except Err:
        pass
```

Output:

```
... nothing, which is correct
```